# Rails ransack use between

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I want search created_at between `Date.today.beginning_of_day..Date.today.end_of_day`

like

```
Order.search({created_at_between: Date.today.beginning_of_day..Date.today.end_of_day }).result
```

but is not work

How do i make to search `created_at` between dates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

config/initializers/ransack.rb

```
Ransack.configure do |config|
  config.add_predicate 'between',
    arel_predicate: 'between',
    formatter: proc { |v|
      parts = v.split(',')
      OpenStruct.new(begin: parts[0], end: parts[1])
    },
    validator: proc { |v| v.present? },
    type: :string
end
```

Then `created_at_between '2014-01-01,2014-01-02'` works!

Answer (score 1):

here is the solution,

```
params[:q] = {:created_at_gt => Date.current.beginning_of_day, :created_at_lt => Date.current.end_of_day}

Order.search(params[:q]).result
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the accepted answer from Frank except the version of arel I was using did not have 'between' defined.  So if you are using an older version, see my quick and dirty solution below.

In my view I have a ransack search field like

```
= f.text_field :request_date_between, class: 'daterange'
```

That will send a date to the controller like

> '2015-10-01 to 2015-10-31'

then in my down and dirty ransack.rb initializer I have;

```
Ransack.configure do |config|
  config.add_predicate 'between',
                       arel_predicate: 'between',
                       formatter: proc { |v| v.split(' to ') },
                       type: :string
end

module Arel
  module Predications
    def between other
      gteq(other[0]).and(lt(other[1]))
    end
  end
end
```